# Allure and JUnit 4 with maven : empty xmls in allure-results folder

Tags: maven, junit, allure

I followed the following instruction to add support of Aluure with JUnit 4:
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/wiki/JUnit

If i run my suite via cmd ( mvn clean test -Dtest=MySuiteName ) i got allure-results folder with several xml's with empty body.
(refer to screesnhot)
[image]

And if i run:
mvn allure:serve

I got:
[image]

Could somebody provide me working pom.xml example with JUnit 4 (with suites) and Allure ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by myself by changing to:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

By the way, why allure reports does not generated by running via Intellij IDEA ?

It generates only via cmd run.